# PHP code fails in main server

Tags: php, javascript

I have integrated a Pop up window(new browser window) control on click of a link. It works
really well on local server(PHP 5.3) but not in the main server(PHP 5.1)

Here's the Javascript code to pop up window

```
window.open ('http://www.xyzsite.com/edo/hints.php?Para1='+hin, '', 'width=250,height=100');
```

Is it because of difference in PHP version or any other configuration difference I should look for?
Please give me ur inputs.

Comment: You'll need to explain what "code fails" entails. Are there any error messages?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with PHP.

Comment: @Mark Elliot the question mentions PHP once in the title and 3 times in the question! it has everything to do with PHP :D Javascript is only mentioned once. :D

Comment: I'm guessing the `hints.php` script "works" in development but "fails" in production. karthik will need to elaborate on these rather arbitrary metrics

Comment: sorry for posting incomplete code, am not getting any error message but the window freezes when i click of the link. this is PHP code <div align = "right"; style = "padding-right:200px"> <a href="Javascript:show_hint( <?php echo $id; ?>)">Hints</div>  and in hints.php I use get method to receive the parameter by using GET METHOD  "$id = $_GET[Para1];" thanks again!!

Comment: @karthik edit your question to add more detail, don't add it in comments. Also, you'll have to define "freezes". Does the whole browser lock up? Do you have to kill the process?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript runs on the client computer.  Make sure you are running the same javascript by Ctrl+F5 to ensure non-cached javascript.  The server should have nothing to do with this.

Answer (score -2):

GET parameters are separated with `&` character, not `,`.
Nothing else in code you show is related to PHP

Comment: He only has one get parameter, the others are window features, an argument to [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open)

Comment: , is allowed as an parameter\parameter value separator